# Не работает datagridcheckboxcolumn

Tags: wpf, checkbox, datagrid

Есть datagrid с datagridcheckboxcolumn. Checkboxcolumn привязан к bool элементам коллекции. После изменения стиля Checkbox перестали меняться значения в привязанных элементах. Раньше значения чекбокс меняли значения элемента с false на true, а теперь не меняют
Новый стиль checkbox

```
<!--стиль CheckBoxColumn -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="checkboxcolumn_style">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundNormal}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/WpfApplication3;component/#PT Sans" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="background_checkbox"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" To="{StaticResource BorderBrushGradientColor1}"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="background_checkbox"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" To="{StaticResource BorderBrushGradientColor1}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="background_checkbox"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" To="{StaticResource BorderBrushSolidColor}"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="background_checkbox"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" To="{StaticResource BorderBrushSolidColor}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid Width="14" Height="14">
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Height="12" Width="12" x:Name="background_checkbox" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Path x:Name="check_icon" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" 
                                  Data="M2803 23c252,-27 507,-23 760,-23 8726,1 17451,-1 26177,1 770,-13 1547,254 2131,761 721,605 1135,1544 1113,2483 1,9102 0,18204 0,27306 16,828 -297,1664 -877,2261 -602,644 -1488,1001 -2368,983 -8831,0 -17662,0 -26493,0 -611,10 -1226,-153 -1745,-477 -857,-525 -1432,-1478 -1491,-2482 -16,-295 -8,-591 -10,-885 1,-8902 0,-17804 1,-26706 -19,-889 349,-1779 1004,-2383 487,-465 1130,-758 1798,-839zm22151 5493c-170,24 -342,19 -510,52 -932,146 -1798,654 -2387,1390 -393,480 -839,928 -1124,1485 -81,153 -130,327 -250,456 -2393,2747 -4793,5489 -7184,8238 -56,21 -967,-955 -1066,-1067 -546,-624 -1199,-1181 -1986,-1471 -1080,-425 -2325,-390 -3383,82 -1204,528 -2137,1628 -2462,2902 -103,361 -128,737 -148,1110 22,308 29,618 101,919 155,737 500,1434 1005,1994 1294,1609 3238,3370 4787,4735 494,479 1522,886 2388,895 852,-8 1700,-308 2352,-859 442,-396 805,-867 1201,-1306 3364,-3856 6730,-7710 10093,-11566 162,-146 358,-250 514,-405 197,-143 336,-346 504,-519 232,-285 480,-557 705,-848 421,-535 694,-1184 779,-1859 13,-239 70,-478 31,-718 -33,-452 -129,-901 -312,-1316 -520,-1247 -1752,-2160 -3096,-2297 -185,-4 -367,-55 -552,-27z"
                                  Fill="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundOver}" Height="14" Width="14"/>
                            <Rectangle Height="7" Width="7" x:Name="background_null_checkbox" Fill="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundOver}" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle Height="12" Width="12" x:Name="background_disabled_checkbox" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledBrush}" 
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="check_icon" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="background_null_checkbox" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="background_disabled_checkbox" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.72"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Используемые ресурсы:

```
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackgroundNormal" GradientOrigin="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#7F7F7F" Offset="1" />
    <GradientStop Color="#7F7F7F" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlForeground" Color="#262626" />
<Color x:Key="BorderBrushSolidColor">#7F7F7F</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderBrushGradientColor1">#FF973D</Color>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackgroundOver" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF973D" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#A6A6A6" />
```

Код **XAML**

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding [7], Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="30" CanUserSort="False" ElementStyle="{StaticResource checkboxcolumn_style}" CellStyle="{StaticResource HideLeftRightCellStyle}">
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DGridCentAl}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Viewbox Height="17" Grid.Row="1">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Button Background="Transparent" x:Name="btn_UpCheckedFeed" Click="btn_UpCheckedFeed_Click">
                                                        <Path Fill="#7F7F7F" x:Name="SortColumnIcon" Data="M0 29692l5358 0 0 -13577 -5358 0 0 13577zm6722 8l5402 
                                                              0 0 -29700 -5402 0 0 29700zm6760 0l5402 0 0 -20258 -5402 0 0 20258z"/>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>

                                            </Viewbox>
                                            <Viewbox Height="8" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 0 0 -11" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Button Background="Transparent" x:Name="btn_UncheckedAll" Click="UncheckAll_Click">
                                                        <Polygon Fill="#F79646" Points="0,418 418,0 1463,1045 2508,0 2996,418 1881,1463 
                                                                 2996,2509 2508,2996 1463,1881 418,2996 0,2509 1045,1463 "/>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                            <!--Vertical border-->
                                            <StackPanel x:Name="VerticalSeparator" Grid.RowSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" Visibility="Visible" Fill="#FFF"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Покажите ваши остальные ресурсы: `DisabledBorderBrush` и прочие

Comment: Максим Казанцев, получилось у вас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашему стилю не хватает такой строчки:

```
<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
```

Как я это определил - в дизайнере кликните по заголовку своего *нестилизованного* столбца правой кнопкой и выберите пункт Edit Column Styles - Edit Element Style - Edit a copy и посмотрите как выглядит стандартный стиль.
Он оказался очень прост:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
</Style>
```

Остается только перебором определить чего не хватает.

Имейте ввиду, что теперь ваш стиль придется доработать, так как при клике проявляется стандартный дизайн чекбокса.
Также можно заметить, что если при вашем стиле кликать не по картинке флажка, а рядом с ней, то bool свойство меняется нормально, что в общем-то тоже наводит на мысль, что флажок перекрыт и не прокликивается.

Другое решение - вместо `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` определить `DataGridTemplateColumn` и поместить в него свой стилизованный чекбокс вручную.

Comment: Да получилось, Как вы посоветовали использовал DataGridTemplateColumn вместо DataGridCheckBoxColumn
Так же решилась проблема когда при прокрутке списка вниз появлялись отмеченные чекбоксы и исчезали те которые были отмечены. Спасибо Вам за подробное объяснение

Comment: @Максим Казанцев, пожалуйста. Рад что помог!